# How to add user with out using useradd or similar command?

Tags: linux, bash

How to add user on linux bash script with out using `useradd` or similar command.

Also copy the startup script which located in `/etc/skel/`, and change password for the user which you have been added.

```
user1=$1
read -p "Enter your home name" home_name
read -p "Enter your login shell" loginshell
echo "$user1:x:500:500:$user1:/home/$home_name:$loginshell" >> /etc/passwd 
echo "$user1:x:500:" >> /etc/group
mkdir /home/$home_name
chmod 744 /home/$home_name
cp -pr /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/$home_name
echo "$user1: " >> /etc/shadow
echo "`passwd` $user1"
```

The error i have got it after execute  this script

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

Please could you advice me if there any mistakes?

Comment: This is fundamentally insecure. Why on Earth would you want to avoid the standard, secure, documented, supported tool? In other words, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: _"How to add user on linux bash script"_ ... Simple, just invoke `useradd`.  ... _"with out using `useradd` or similar command."_  Say what?

Answer (score 2):

You should explain why you want to do that. In my opnion, it is a bad idea. In particular, because it does not handle well all the various kind of systems (for instance, some Linux system use LDAP for user authentification, etc).

And I believe that your line `echo "$user1: " >> /etc/shadow` is wrong. Look (with sudo) at the content of the /etc/shadow file, and you'll understand that entries inside are more than just a username followed by a colon.

But really, you should use *useradd* or *adduser* to do that. You are risking to break your system entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
echo "`passwd` $user1"
```

with

```
passwd $user1
```

for entering the first password.

But besides this problem you add all new users with the same user-id and group-id. So there are technically no new users but one user with several "aliases". You have to replace the `500` when writing `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to fix that.

Another big problem is, that the user's new home directory and the startup script do not belong to him but to root. You may add a `chown -R $user1:$user1 /home/$homename` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you should also have something like `echo "$user1: " >> /etc/gshadow` for the group that you are creating. Same as what you have done for the user and the `shadow` file.